# i18n-Frontpage: inconsistent links to non-default language

Tags: i18n-l10n, navigation

I am running across some inconsistent behaviour regarding the links to the  frontpage of my multilingual site. The following is happening:

`mysite.com` -> English frontpage, correct

`mysite.com/en` -> English frontpage, correct

`mysite.com/en/node` -> English frontpage, correct

`mysite.com/de/node` -> German frontpage, correct

`mysite.com/de` -> **English content** but language switcher says it's German, should display German content

Did anyone experience something similar? I have an idea why this is happening but no clue how to fix it.

I didn't find anything here. The closest one was this, but I already have a working link to the German frontpage, so it doesn't really apply to me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168289/multiple-frontpages-in-mutiple-languages.

Best regards,
Christoph

P.S.: All my images with relative links in Blocks or Pages get the language tag set in front of them. Is this a corresponding thing or default i18n behaviour? I just hotfixed it with softlinks from `en/images` and `de/images` to `images`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What eventually worked for me:

**Disable the module "admin_language"**

I tried many different configurations of this module but it just kept on giving me English content on the German Frontpage. Views however displayed the correct language.

Should I report this bug to the module maintainers?